# Assets file project.assets.json doesnot have a target for netcoreapp version v1.1

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

publish failed, target version is netcore2.0.0 migrated from netcore1.0.0

[image: publish failed]

attached API.csproj file

[image]

tried:
**clean,
delete bin/obj
rebuild** 
Any ideas?